# Why won't server 2008 let me change my password policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, password

I need to keep the same password indefinitely for the administrator account on a Windows Server 2008 machine.  I've found Start | Administrative Tools | Local Security Policy, but whether or not I run this as an administrator, the controls for editing things like 'Enforce password history' are greyed out.  How can I edit the policy?

(I have the same problem when I access the console via gpedit.msc.)

Comment: This comes up waaay too often for service accounts.

Answer (score 3):

This is how i did it. (for others with the same question)

```
Start > Run > gpmc.msc
```

Right click

```
Default Domain Policy > Edit
```

Expand:

```
Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Account Policies > Password Policy
```

You will see the password policies.

Double click on one of them and change to your need!

You may need to run `gpupdate` for a fast group policy update.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're on a domain so local policy options aren't available - I think you need the Group Policy Management Console instead.

The path outlined in [this earlier SF post](https://serverfault.com/questions/19611/disable-password-complexity-rule-in-active-directory) is the way to go.

Comment: OS can't find gpmc.msc.  Hm.  Guess I need to do some research on Active Directory.  Thanks for the lead, though.