# How to Edit Domain Password Complexity?

Tags: windows-server-2003

My Domain Environment is

2 Domain Controller ( Main & Secondary )

DHCP

Mail Server

Internet Server & ISA Server

2 DNS Server Primary & Secondary

My problem i tried to Remove Password Complexity in my 2 domain Controller but i still receive error message that the password doesn't meet password complexity and i tried to run gpupdate /force after i disabled password complexity and check other condition

any one know why

I use windows server 2003 Stand alone

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you did something like [what's described here](https://serverfault.com/questions/19611/disable-password-complexity-rule-in-active-directory). If you created a new GPO at the root of the domain, rather than editing the "Default Domain Policy" be sure that the new GPO has a lower "link order" number than the "Default Domain Policy". GPOs with a lower "link order" are applied last, and thus have a "higher precedence". (The whole idea of "precedence" in GPOs frustrates me... It's SO much easier to just think about it like "This GPO is applied over the other GPOs, so the settings here end up overriding previously-applied GPOs..." )

(While I'm complaining: I wish Microsoft would make up their mind re: dialogs that "order" items in "precedence" whether items lower in the list have a higher "precedence" than items higher in the list, etc. Globally, every part of the OS, and arguably all of their products, should follow the same pattern.)